# Purchased Web template. Index file is PHP instead of HTML, how do I edit the template?

Tags: php, html

I purchased a marketplace template. I am used to see `index.html` files when I load them into brackets for editing. This template however has an `index.php` file.

My question is how do I go about editing the `index.php` file? Would it be the same as I would with an `index.html` file? Brackets also does not read PHP and I would have to run it from a server with the host name url (something I also don't know how to do).

Comment: Look into Xampp to run a php file on localhost, it's free and fairly simple to use.[xampp on sourceforge](http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/)

Answer (score 0):

To execute php files, you have to use a local web server as [Billy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4118466/billy) points out. On Windows and Mac you can use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org) to do so, on Linux you should prefer setting up a LAMP-Server ([Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)).

After you installed your webserver you have to save your files under the server's document root. You can find it at the place where you installed XAMPP under the folder `/htdocs` (the place on Linux varies, on the latest Ubuntu flavors it should point to `/var/www/html`) You have to move all the files there. Now, you can open those files in your web browser by opening `localhost/your-folder/index.php`.

Edit your PHP files as you'd normally do in Brackets, it can handle PHP files. To use the Live Preview feature you have to go to `File → Project Settings` and enter your path with localhost here (don't add the file name, Brackets will do that for you) e.g. `http://localhost/your-folder` and you should be all set and running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use live editor to edit your php file such as https://c9.io/ and its one installation is free and that's how you can upload your files: https://docs.c9.io/discuss/5582d455ea39a93900224238 . Just start custom php project and make it private.